# What does "过SOR了吗" mean?

Tags: internet-slang

It appears in a WeChat sticker with a megaphone yelling "过SOR了吗" at a cartoon character. The cartoon character is holding a laptop and flinching and sweating because of the loud megaphone.

I understand the `过` + `了` pattern but the "SOR" piece confuses me.

Here's what the sticker looks like:

> [image]

Comment: I added a gif of the sticker into the question. I'm assuming it is the correct one. Let me know.

Comment: @Mo. : Yeah! That's the sticker.

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe "**S**pecification **o**f **R**equirements". I imagine that the character holding the megaphone is the team manager, while the one being yelled at is a software engineer. It would be nice to have a screenshot of that sticker to illustrate the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a WeChat sticker so I think it's copyrighted. I don't have permission to distribute it. I can't find a link to it online anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, that sticker collection's name is "职场达人独乐乐" by "陈小桃&北京天和合择". Unfortunately, I can't get that sticker image out of wechat.

Since that there is a sticker in the collection which has the caption "做 Deck, 做 Deck" which means "make keynote" or "make slide presentation files", and lots of them are related with work, I would agree with @FirminMartin , SOR means "**S**pecification **o**f **R**equirements" or "**S**tate **o**f **R**equirements"

Answer (score 1):

See  https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SOR

Depend on the context, it could be anything on the list. If the cartoon character is holding a laptop and flinching and sweating, he might be watching something he shouldn't. Or he is not allowed to use the laptop

One of the acronym  definition of SOR is "Sex Offender Registry".

"过SOR了吗” could mean "have you been cleared from the Sex Offender Registry?"

One of the restrictions on people on the SOR might be 'forbidden to access the internet' if it was the primary source for him to find his victims

Answer (score 1):

SOR is probably referring to ***sorcerer*** in the PC game 暗黑破坏神.

I haven't played the game.  But the context seems to indicate that the cartoon character is playing the game with his laptop and megaphone is yelling at him whether he has passed the *sorcerer* stage.

This is just a guess work.  I may be wrong about it, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be: [System of record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record)

> A system of record (SOR) or source system of record (SSoR) is a data management term for an information storage system (commonly implemented on a computer system running a database management system) that is the authoritative data source for a given data element or piece of information. The need to identify systems of record can become acute in organizations where management information systems have been built by taking output data from multiple source systems, re-processing this data, and then re-presenting the result for a new business use.

Here's a Chinese blog talking about System of Record, [缓存模式](https://hypc.github.io/2019/07/15/cache-pattern/):

> 常见的模式有分为两大类：Cache-aside以及Cache-as-SoR。
>
> SoR(system-of-record)：记录系统，或者可以叫做数据源，即实际存储原始数据的系统。
>
> Cache：缓存，是SoR的快照数据，Cache的访问速度比SoR要快，放入Cache的目的是提升访问速度，减少回源到SoR的次数。
>
> **Cache-aside**
>
> 访问记录系统（SoR）的应用程序代码应首先查询缓存，如果缓存包含数据，则直接从缓存返回数据，绕过SoR。 否则，应用程序代码必须从记录系统获取数据，将数据存储在缓存中，然后返回它。写入数据时，必须同时更新缓存以及记录系统。